Linear algebra: calculation exercise, influence change of basis on a given linear map?
Suppose I have a matrix
$A$ = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
In my book they say that $A$ can be written as
$\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & -1 & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$ (let's call this second matrix $A^*$) "in" the orthogonal basis $\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 1\\ 0\\\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ -1\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix} \}$, but I don't understand what this means and how they figured this out.

Please note that it isn't an orthogonal basis, I think there's is a typo in my notes because this is an exact copy op my notes.


@AnneBauval Oh yes I see it now, the inproduct of two of those basis vectors is not zero.

What do you know about the matrix representation(s) of a linear map?

@AnneBauval The column vectors are the coordinates of the image of the basis vectors with respect to "original" the basis vectors?

Ok (except I don't understand why you wrote "original"). Now, denoting by $u,v,w$ your three vectors, check that $Au=u, Av=-v,Aw=v+w$.

@AnneBauval Okay, I see this is indeed true.

@AnneBauval I think the "original" is not necessary and indeed confusing and unclear, and that the sentence is correct without it.

@AnneBauval But why do we apply $A$ to the standard basis vectors to obtain $A^*$?

We don't. We apply it to u,v,w,  which is not the standard basis. The columns of $A^*$ are the coordinates of $Au, Av,Aw$ in the basis $(u,v,w)$. This is what you checked.

@AnneBauval alright, I see it now.

Denote by $u,v,w$ your three vectors.
By definition, the columns of $A^∗$ are the coordinates of $Au,Av,Aw$ in the basis $(u,v,w)$. This new matrix $A^*$ being the one written in your book means that
$$Au=u,\quad Av=−v,\quad Aw=v+w.$$
